# How to replace based on regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have json array like that:

```
   [
   {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Mr",  
        "name": "Harry Robinson",
        "company": "ResearchBch",
        "email": "anything",
        "age": 38,
        "startDate": "2015/07/25",
        "salary": "$421069.74"
    },
    ...
    ]
```

I want to replace all `"email": "anything"` to `"email": "anything@test.com"`
How can I do that with Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all email addresses currently don't have `@test.com`:

Search:

```
("email": ")(.*)(")
```

(Find `"email": "`, `anything`, `"`)

Replace with:

```
\1\2@test.com\3
```

(Replace with group 1 (`"email": "`), group 2 (`anything`), add `@test.com`, group 3 `"`)

[image]

Comment: I am just thinking and writing same answer. Nice.